# XSL how to exclude some children in output?

Tags: xslt

Beginner XSL question..and I know there are similar questions and answers posted, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my XSLT...

My source XML looks like (this is just a fragment of a much larger XML file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION><Release NAME="Release" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<Transaction>
    <TransactionNumber>4</TransactionNumber>
    <ReleaseNumber>4</ReleaseNumber>
    <PrimaryObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPart:121581:416986630-1502721046884-982634822-1-0-0-127@ODIGettingStarted.tri.co.uk</PrimaryObjectID>
    <CreatedBy>orgadmin</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedDate>2017-09-27 08:34:31 EDT</CreatedDate>
    <Locale>en_US</Locale>
    <Destination>CRP1</Destination>
</Transaction>
</Release>
```

I want to exclude the Locale and Destination nodes from the output.
My complete solution will be more complex that requires me to split the XML into three, hence my use of  but the relevant code I have so far is :-

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "2.0"
    xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name ="outputFileDir" select="'file:///D:/workspace/TPHMOT_xsl/TPHMOT_xsl/xsl_output'"/> 

    <xsl:template match ="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="{$outputFileDir}/ESI_ItemMasters_1.xml" method="xml" indent="yes">
            <COLLECTION>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="COLLECTION/Release"/>
            </COLLECTION>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$outputFileDir}/ESI_ConfigurableItem_1.xml" method="xml" indent="yes">
            <COLLECTION>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="COLLECTION/Release"/>
            </COLLECTION>       
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$outputFileDir}/ESI_GenericBOM_1.xml" method="xml" indent="yes">
            <COLLECTION>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="COLLECTION/Release"/>
            </COLLECTION>       
        </xsl:result-document>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Release">
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
   <Release NAME="Release" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <Transaction>
         <TransactionNumber>4</TransactionNumber>
         <ReleaseNumber>4</ReleaseNumber>
         <PrimaryObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPart:121581:416986630-1502721046884-982634822-1-0-0-127@ODIGettingStarted.tri.co.uk</PrimaryObjectID>
         <CreatedBy>orgadmin</CreatedBy>
         <CreatedDate>2017-09-27 08:34:31 EDT</CreatedDate>
         <Locale>en_US</Locale>
         <Destination>CRP1</Destination>
      </Transaction>
   </Release>
</COLLECTION>
```

How can I adapt my XSL to exclude Locale and Destination child nodes?

Many thanks in advance for any help offered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying your complete element in

```
<xsl:template match="Release">
    <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

you only need to use the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then empty template(s) to prevent the elements you don't want from being copied:

```
<xsl:template match="Locale | Destination"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly worked, I need to get my head around this apply-templates pattern, it's not sunk in yet!